# Play + JPA + Hibernate + PostgreSQL: Cannot create Tables

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, playframework

I've been trying to create a simple and small application using Play Framework 2.4.0, JPA, and Hibernate 4.3.9 to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database. I want the application to create new database tables based on the models created on the application. So far, I've had no success.

This is the content of my "build.sbt":

```
name := """aplicacion1"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaJpa,
  //"org.apache.directory.api" % "apache-ldap-api" % "1.0.0-M14",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.3.9.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final"

)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

This is the content of my "application.conf" describing the database conection:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://postgres:passsuper@localhost/tesis_play1"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

This is the content of my "persistence.xml":

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And this is the small model class I'm trying to get into the database:

```
@Entity
public class ruta {

    @Id
    public int idRuta;
    public String nombre;
    public boolean esIda;
    public boolean esvuelta;
    public String apodo1;
    public String apodo2;
    public String ref;

}
```

The application compiles and runs with no errors, but the "ruta" table is never created on the database. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: The following appears on the console when accessing the application through "localhost:9000":

```
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to C:\Users\Enrique\Desktop\tesis_2\aplicacion1\target\scala-2.11\classes...
SLF4J: The following set of substitute loggers may have been accessed
SLF4J: during the initialization phase. Logging calls during this
SLF4J: phase were not honored. However, subsequent logging calls to these
SLF4J: loggers will work as normally expected.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
SLF4J: org.webjars.CloseQuietly
[info] - application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] - play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool - datasource [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/tesis_play1] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] - play.api.db.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://localhost/tesis_play1
[info] - play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] - play.api.Play$ - Application started (Dev)
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in JPA, but maybe in your application.conf the line `db.default.url` is wrong: Normally it looks more like `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_database` and the password and user name you might have to define in additional lines `db.default.user=myusername` and `db.default.password=mypassword`.

Comment: @Kris I tried it that way, but the result is the same: tables are still not being created :(

Comment: What's in your log if you add `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` to your persistance.xml?

Comment: @Kris you mean the console output? I get the same output that I included at the end of the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generated hbm2ddl database changes are called when Hibernate `SessionFactory` is created. Starting application does not create `EntityManagerFactory` and underlying Hibernate `SessionFactory`.

Changes on database will be made on first call to JPA, when EntityManagerFactory is created. To start EntityManagerFactory when your app starts, just create [Global class](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaGlobal) with JPA call:

```java
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public void onStart(Application app) {

        JPA.withTransaction(new F.Callback0() {
            @Override
            public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                play.Logger.debug("First JPA call");
            }
        });


    }

    public void onStop(Application app) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. Created a a Global class inside controllers package, then added "application.global = controllers.Global" to application.conf, but tables are still not being created :( Also tried moving the Global class to the default package, but still no results

Comment: Did you include JPA.withTransaction in Global.onStart? I have tested with configuration identical to yours and tables were created.

Comment: Yes, I included that. I don't know if this might be important, but in this project I have a "lib" directory with the following jars : hibernate-spatial-4.3, jts-1.13, jtsio-1.13, postgis-jdbc-2.1.7, postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41. No results so far

Comment: I included a simple "System.out.println("GLOBAL");" inside the "invoke" method of the "onStart" method. It's not getting printed. I guess the "onStart" method is not being executed when the app starts.

Comment: Ignore my last 2 comments, it was an error on my part: I was making a wrong import on the file containing the Global object ("Global.java"). I was using "import controllers.Application;" (which is the default controller Play creates on a new project), when instead it had ti be "import play.Application;". Thanks a lot @Pawel !! you just saved me from throwing my pc through the window :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to add this to your `persistence.xml`:

```
....
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
...
```

I'm no JPA expert myself but this seems like the only difference between your `persistence.xml` and the one I have in a project of mine. According to the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html) this property will:

> Determine which element is auto discovered by Hibernate Entity Manager while parsing the .par archive. (default to class,hbm).

It says it should default to `class,hbm` but I'd still try anyway. Outside of that the only other thing I could recommend is to try to add the database driver and credentials in the `persistence.xml` like:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="foobar"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:play"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
```

Comment: Just added that line to persistence.xml, but still no results :(

Comment: @Eduardo Weird.. perhaps you could try doing a `play clean` and then run it again

Comment: Just did a clean to the project, but still no results